# MALLOC_CHECK_ for linux daemons

Tags: c, heap-corruption

Can we use MALLOC_CHECK_ for linux daemon processes?

Basically I want to examine an another process(a C program) which runs as daemon and is crashing when my application(a C program) is using it(other process).
The crash is as follows:

```
#0  0xffffe430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xf7426e30 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0xf7428765 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0xf7465d75 in __libc_message () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0xf746bd04 in malloc_printerr () from /lib/libc.so.6
#5  0xf746d613 in _int_free () from /lib/libc.so.6
#6  0xf747074d in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
#7  0xf6043a61 in BufferFree (memblk=0xf1f82f90) at ../allocator/alloclib.c:447
```

Is there any other way to debug other then valgrind?

Comment: Can't you just recompile the deamon with debug info and run it inside a debugger, for example gdb?

Comment: I have already tried that and received the above crash with debug info enabled.

But since it shows the stack trace at the final stage when the problematic memory location is accessed.
I want the trace when the memory gets corrupted and so I want to use MALLOC_CHECK.

Comment: I'd say that you didn't..
- rebuild the deamon with -g (or, if it uses automake and friends there maybe is a make debug, or similar)
- run gdb with the name of the executable
- type run
when it crashes it will eventually stop on the line that caused the fault.

Anyway, it probably is a double free or a buffer overflow, if you have any ideas on where it could happen..

Answer (score 2):

## How to enable MALLOC_CHECK_

The below article explains the usage of MALLOC_CHECK_

**MALLOC_CHECK_** can be used in the script from where you are triggering your daemons. Below export in the script will enable malloc check for all the daemons which are triggered using the script.

```
export MALLOC_CHECK_=X, Where X can be 0,1 or 3
```

> If MALLOC_CHECK_ is set to 0 (zero), the memory management functions
> are simply most tolerant of errors and do not give warnings. Maybe be
> useful if we are prevented from finding one memory bug by another that
> is not convenient to fix at the moment; it might allow us to use other
> tools to chase down the other memory bug. It may also be useful if you
> are running code that works on another system but not on Linux.  It
> can provide a quick workaround that may allow the code to temporarily
> function before you have the chance to resolve the error.
>
> If MALLOC_CHECK_ is set to 1 (one), the memory management functions
> print out warning messages on standard error when problems are
> noticed. It is useful if we are not aware of any problems and just
> wants to be notified if any problem exists.
>
> If MALLOC_CHECK_ is set to 2 (two), the memory management functions
> call abort()when problems are noticed. This is most useful from inside
> the debugger or a shell starting an application or daemon.  It allows
> a backtrace to be obtained as soon as the memory management functions
> discover an error, providing information closest to the point at which
> the error has happened. If a core is caused by memory corruption, we
> have more information about memory allocations.  This is better for
> troubleshooting and determining where/which application overwrote a
> memory address.
>
> Settings 1 and 2 can be combined by setting MALLOC_CHECK_ to 3
> (three).  This will enable the print out of warning messages on
> standard error (1) and will call abort() when problems are noticed.